# Split string every defined repeat of the delimiter

Tags: php, string

> This is a string. Without any new lines. I need the newlines to make
>   paragraphs. I decided to use follow-stop i.e the dot followed by white
>   space to make paragraphs every two occurance of those dots in the
>   string.

In the above dummy string, as it describes, I need to split the string every occurrence of `.` that followed by a white space to add `\n` or `<p>` tag.

The only way that I know is `explode`., then loop inside the array and continue after every two elements. However, it will split the string  regardless  its following with space or not.

Also, this process may have performance issues.

I need to know if there is a way to do that more accurate and efficient.

```
$arr = explode('.',$mystring);
$output = '';
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
  $output .= $arr[$i].'. ';
  if (isset($arr[$i+1])){
   $output .= $arr[$i+1].'. '."\n";
   $i++;
  }
  else{
   $output .= '. '."\n";
  }
}
```

In other words, the above quoted string should look like:

```
This is a string. Without any new lines.
I need the newlines to make paragraphs. I decided to use follow-stop i.e the dot followed by white space to make paragraphs every two occurance of those dots in the string.
```

Comment: Either use '. ' (dot followed by whitespace) as explode character, or regex.

Comment: @baao do you mean using `preg_split` ? If that it is, is there a regex keep repetition in count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a regex approach?

```
$string = 'This is a string. Without any new lines. I need the newlines to make paragraphs. I decided to use follow-stop i.e the dot followed by white space to make paragraphs every two occurance of those dots in the string.';
preg_match_all('~((?:.+?\.){2})(.*)~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is a string. Without any new lines. I need the newlines to make paragraphs. I decided to use follow-stop i.e the dot followed by white space to make paragraphs every two occurance of those dots in the string.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is a string. Without any new lines.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  I need the newlines to make paragraphs. I decided to use follow-stop i.e the dot followed by white space to make paragraphs every two occurance of those dots in the string.
        )

)
```

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iV1gR1/1

`0` is the whole found expression. `1` is the first captured group (aka the first 2 sentences). `2` is the remaining content.

Actually on re-reading question, are you trying to split on every sentence? If so maybe this is what you'd want:

```
$string = 'This is a string. Without any new lines. I need the newlines to make paragraphs. I decided to use follow-stop i.e the dot followed by white space to make paragraphs every two occurance of those dots in the string.';
preg_match_all('~(.+?[.?!])(?:\s+|$)~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is a string.
    [1] => Without any new lines.
    [2] => I need the newlines to make paragraphs.
    [3] => I decided to use follow-stop i.e the dot followed by white space to make paragraphs every two occurance of those dots in the string.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str = str_replace(". ", ".\n", $str);
```

Comment: 2 isn't a valid argument for `int &$count` in that function.

Comment: This do not offer the required result. It will replace every `. `. However, I need replace it every two occurrence of `. ` @worldofjr